# Flutter InAppWebView iOS goes to live broadcast instead of camera

Tags: ios, flutter, webview, camera

I'm using the [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) package to show our website as a web view in our Flutter iOS app. The website supports video recording, and everything works fine on the web.

**Whenever the user starts recording from the app, it accidentally redirects them to `live broadcast` instead of the camera.**

It's a bit complicated to explain, So I'm attaching this short video:

[image]

Any suggestions why it happens? Is that an `InAppWebView` issue?

Check out our [discussion](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1248) on GitHub.

flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.7, on macOS 13.0 22A380 darwin-x64, locale en-IL)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability
```

IOS version: 15.2.1

## Update

Facing the exact same issue also on the [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) package.

Both the flutter_inappwebview and flutter_webview_plugin packages didn't provide full detailed information about their dependencies, but they both encountered the same issue on opening a video recording.

Our [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1248#issuecomment-1336384448) is getting advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem Solved!

Thanks to `@pichillilorenzo` `@programming6131`, they helped me to figure out this issue in our [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview/issues/1248).

All I had to do is to add `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` to my `InAppWevViewGroupOption`:

```
initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
  crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
      useShouldOverrideUrlLoading: true,
      mediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture: false,
  ),
  android: AndroidInAppWebViewOptions(
      useHybridComposition: true,
  ),
  ios: IOSInAppWebViewOptions(
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback: true, // <-- add this line
  ),
)
```

According to Apple [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebviewconfiguration/1614793-allowsinlinemediaplayback?language=objc) `allowsInlineMediaPlayback` is a boolean value that indicates whether HTML5 videos play inline or use the native full-screen controller.

Set this property to **YES to play videos inline**, or NO to use the native full-screen controller.

When adding a video element to an HTML document on iPhone, **you must also include the `playsinline` attribute**.
The default value of this property is NO for iPhone and YES for iPad.

Answer (score -1):

remove the **userAgent** from **InAppWebViewOptions**

Comment: Hey @dhruvil welcome to the StackOverflow community. Please provide more information when answering questions, so others will understand you better. What is the `userAgent` and how is it relevant to this issue? (you can update your answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).